# How to move expandableRows icon to the right side of the data grid, in react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, expandable, react-data-table-component

As of now the prop expandableRows puts the icon in the left side, however I need to see the icon in right most of the table. Is there any way to do this?

How to move expandableRows icon to the right side of the row, in react-data-table-component. As of now it is displaying in the left side. How to get the icon in the right side of the row (at the end of row) in react-data-table.

Ant design table has- "expandIconColumnIndex={4}" allows to place the icon in desired index. Do we have same kind of thing in "react-data-table"?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the direction of the table to `rtl` and then reset it back to `ltr` on each cell.

```css
.rdt_Table{
    direction:rtl
}
.rdt_TableCell, .rdt_TableCol{
    direction:ltr
}
```